# Multiprocessing separation of tasks

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have two different tasks that I want to split amongst processes. I have one task that consists of retrieving responses from URLs and writing the responses to a `Queue` (multiprocessing Queue, not threading) which I would like to have a few processes working on in parallel.

I have another task that waits for the `Queue` to be have response data, retrieves responses from it, and writes to a file. I want to have one process work on this.

The problem is if I start a pool of processes working on hitting the URLs, the writing processes won't start until all of the processes are done. How do I start the pool of processes to hit the URLs and start the process to write to a file at the same time/one after the other?

My code:

```
CSV = CHANNEL + ".csv"
    response_queue = Queue()

    urls = []
    for row in read_channel_data(CSV):
        url = "https://some_domain/%s" % row[1]
        urls.append(url)

    # This process will start and wait for response_queue to fill up inside func
    write_process = Process(target=func, args=(response_queue,))
    write_process.start()
    write_process.join()

    # This never starts
    pool = Pool(processes=PROCESSES)
    pool.map_async(get_data, urls)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the call to `write_process.join()` until after the call to `pool.join()`. The `join` call is blocking until `func` exits, which won't happen unless the `pool` stuff runs. So just call `start`, and hold off on calling `join` until you've been able to run the `pool` code.